# Can someone show me a proof or at least an intuitive explanation as to why the Boltzmann factor is equal to this?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

In my thermodynamics class, the professor used the result:

$$\exp\left(\frac{\epsilon_j -\epsilon_i}{\kappa T} \right) = \frac{p_i}{p_j}$$

However there was no proof or actually any explanation for this. Could you link me one, show me a quick proof or at least an explanation? Thank you.

Comment: What textbook are you using? The Boltzmann factor should be derived early on in any thermodynamics textbook.

Comment: @Andrew I'm using my teacher's notes, no textbook. Strangely, he doesn't include a proof for this.

Comment: Check out Section 1.3 of David Tong's thermodynamics notes https://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/statphys.html